# Appium terminate vs close

Tags: appium, python-appium

In Appium, what is the technical difference between the `driver.terminate_app(bundleId)` and `driver.close_app()` methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**driver.terminate_app(bundleId)->**

Terminates an existing application on the device. If the application is not running then the returned result will be **false**, otherwise **true**.

**Supported arguments**

*bundleId*: The bundle identifier of the application, which is going to be terminated. Mandatory argument.

Where **driver.close_app()** is actually used to end the session of the driver with the app. It is mostly written in the @AfterTest method that means after the executions of all of your tests the instance of the driver should be safely closed.

See the below code for driver.close()

```
public class Github1298Test {
  @BeforeMethod
  public void setUp() {
    //initiate your driver instance 
   //give all capabilities 

  }

 @Test
 public void tearDown() {
    driver.close_app();
 }
```

}

Comment: After more playing around quite a bit, I note that `driver.close_app()` closes the session communication and driver connection, BUT leaves the session active in Appium (until the `newCommentTimeout` capability causes Appium to terminate it?) and does not close the app if running or backgrounded on the device, while `driver.quit()` will end the Appium session and close the app if running on the device.